# Set up asp.net calendar in russian culture with Cyrillic script

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

is it possible to set language of the asp.net calendar control to russian ?

With Cyrillic script ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the page's culture to Russian? For example, you could put the following code in your pages Page_Load(...) function

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Culture = "ru-RU";
    this.UICulture = "ru-RU";            
}
```